# keep getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'database')

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

my express server is giving me the error:
C:.........\server\src\models\index.js:8
config.db.database,
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'database')
at Object. (C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS\server\src\models\index.js:8:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS\server\src\app.js:5:22)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.db.database,
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.options

)


fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter((file) =>
        file !== 'index.js'
    )
    .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
    db[model.name] = model
    })

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize



module.export = db
```

heres the config file

```
module.export = {
    port: process.env.PORT || 8081,
    db: {
        database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'tabtracker',
        user: process.env.DB_USER || 'tabtracker',
        password: process.env.PASS || 'tabtracker',
        options: {
            dialect: process.env.DIALECT || 'sqlite',
            host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
            storage: './tabtracker.sqlite'

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty clear from the error message that this is an issue with the config variable. config.db is being read as undefined.

First thing I would do is confirm that the path on the require "../config/config" is correct. If it is, then this is almost certainly some kind of syntax issue. I've never used the syntax "module.export", always been "module.exports". Seems unlikely that's the issue, and I know that there are multiple ways to accomplish exporting.

I'd be curious to see if you did a console.log(config) on line 6 what would print. Seems like you could zero in on the issue quite a bit by seeing if that is an incomplete object or if it's undefined.